# WAR file generated by Spring Boot, is it a standard ZIP format?

Tags: java, bash, tomcat, spring-boot

This war file begins with `#!/bin/bash` and followed some bash scripts, then followed by a ZIP magic 'PK'.

I wonder whether it is a standard ZIP format. Can I regard it as a standard WAR file and put it into Apache Tomcat's web-apps folder?

Comment: Ya sure you can put it into the tomcat. Its standard WAR file

Comment: Quick test: does `> unzip file.war` work? Yes: it's a zip file. No: it's not a zip file.

Answer (score 0):

WAR file is zip file with defined structure. It must has `META-INF`, `WEB-INF`, `web.xml` `*.class` folders/files etc.

[image]

Although you create WAR file use Spring Boot or other Java web framework (Apache Struts 1, Apache Struts 2, Stripe etc.), it always follow WAR file conventions.

Offical reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadx.html

Comment: But it does not match ZIP file's convention, i.e. not begin with 'PK' ZIP magic head

Comment: That's because it's an executable .war file.

Comment: The executable flag is an option by the way. You've enabled it (it's not there by default).

Comment: Has this changed over the releases?  I'm using Boot 2.3.2 and I'm noticing the plugin-created WAR file cannot be extracted by AWS Elastic Beanstalk, but older releases like Boot 2.0.1 had no issue.  When I unzip the 2.3.2 WAR it reveals a "cpgz" file inside.